# HTML is being rendered as plain text

Tags: python, html, fastapi

I am using deta to render HTML using the cloud.

Here I have this code:

```py
from deta import Deta
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, Form, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()
deta = Deta(deta_key)

def getVidHtml():
    vids = videos.list()
    html = "<h1> nice html! </h1>"

    return html

@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def root(request: Request):
    vidhtml = getVidHtml()
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request, "vidHtml": vidhtml})
```

But instead of:
`<h1> nice html! </h1>`
it is:
`&lt;h1&gt; nice html! &lt;/h1&gt;`

how do  fix this?

Comment: You are not incluiding your template `index.html`, but loooks like you need to manage the escaping of the html chars https://tedboy.github.io/jinja2/templ10.html

Comment: If you're giving preconfigured HTML to your template and want to trust it as safe HTML, add the `| safe` modifier after your template variable (`{{ vidHtml | safe }}`). You'll have to make sure that a user can't inject any unescaped content into the HTML in that case. However, I'm not sure if your way of rendering HTML is the approriate way; usually you'd give the list of videos to the template, and then let the template create the HTML - not give it a prerendered set of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm looks fine to me.

```html
from deta import Deta
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, Form, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()
deta = Deta(deta_key)

def getVidHtml():
    vids = videos.list()
    html = "<h1> nice html! </h1>"

    return html

@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def root(request: Request):
    vidhtml = getVidHtml()
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request, "vidHtml": vidhtml})
```

```html
from deta import Deta
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, Form, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()
deta = Deta(deta_key)

def getVidHtml():
    vids = videos.list()
    html = "<h1> nice html! </h1>"

    return html

@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def root(request: Request):
    vidhtml = getVidHtml()
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request, "vidHtml": vidhtml})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).